# Codeigniter view file displayed before facebook login

Tags: php, facebook, codeigniter

I have successfully integrated facebook connect in my codeigniter application, but I have come across a weird glitch.

The process in my login controller as follows:

1. Check if user has facebook session
2. If user is logged into facebook and has already given permission, he should be redirected to his profile page on my application
3. If no session, or if the user is logged into facebook but no permissions given, the login form(view file) should be displayed with no redirect

The problem I am facing is, if a user has facebook logged in and already given permissions and if he accesses the login page, the login form is displayed briefly, and then after a second or two, he is redirected to his profile page. Why is the login form even displayed? After all the code `$this->load->view('login_form');` executes at the last line of the controller after checking all the above.

So right now, it occurs that the login_form view file is displayed first, and then it checks for facebook session and after that it redirects.

Added the controller code:

```
$this->load->library('facebook');
$user = $this->facebook->getUser();
if($user)
        {   try{
                $fb_data = $this->facebook->api('/me');
            }
            catch(FacebookApiException $e)
            {
                error_log('from the login: ' . $e);
                $user = null;        
            }
        }
if($user)
{
//below line checks if facebook email is in database
if($this->ion_auth->email_check($fb_data['email'])
{
redirect('my_profile');
}
}
//user not logged in display login page
$this->load->view('login_form');
```

And on my login form, I am using the facebook javascript connect button. Pressing the button opens the facebook oauth dialog page, and after executing, the original login page is refreshed by javascript.

Comment: Can you post your controller code so we can take a look?

Comment: @davidethell parts of the controller code added.

Answer (score 1):

```
$this->load->library('facebook');
$user = $this->facebook->getUser();
if($user)
        {   try{
                $fb_data = $this->facebook->api('/me');
            }
            catch(FacebookApiException $e)
            {
                error_log('from the login: ' . $e);
                $user = null;        
            }
        }
if($user)
{
//below line checks if facebook email is in database
if($this->ion_auth->email_check($fb_data['email'])
{
redirect('my_profile');
}
}else{
//user not logged in display login page
$this->load->view('login_form');
}
```

the code is still being executed because it has not been told otherwise, try this and see.

Comment: When I said `redirect` stops the execution of the script, it doesn't. Your code doesn't help.

Comment: @WebNovice have you tried it? because redirect is not currently stopping it.

Comment: Thanks, but its not working. I believe its something to do with the javascript facebook connect button.

Answer (score 0):

> Why is the login form even displayed?

Because you executed a method that has HTML code put out to the browser …?

> After all the code $this->load->view('login_form'); executes at the last line of the controller

Why is it executed *at all* if previous conditions add up to the login form not being necessary to be displayed at all?

Comment: If all conditions add up, there is a `redirect('my_profile)` within the code before it reaches the load view file code. So, it should never reach the load view file code. But what happens is, even if it satisfies the conditions, the view file is displayed, then after a second it checks for facebook sessions and then it is redirected.

Comment: Isn't the codeigniter's `redirect` function supposed to stop further code execution below it and send it to the redirected page? It does that in all my other controllers.

Comment: @WebNovice try putting a die after the redirect and see what happens

Comment: Ok, I looked up the `redirect` function, and there is `exit()` called at the end of it. So its supposed to stop code execution after `redirect` is called.